# Why $\delta=\min\{1/3M , 1\}$ in this limit proof in Silverman's textbook?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I'm learning Silverman's "Modern calculus and analytic geometry", on page 166 example 2, there is a proof of $$\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{1}{x^2-1}=\infty$$
The original text is:

> The function
>   $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2-1} \qquad(x\neq \pm 1)$$
>   approaches $\infty$ as $x\to 1$. In fact, given any M>0, choose $\delta = \min \{1/3M, 1\}$. Then $0<|x-1|<\delta$ implies $1<|x+1|<3$ and (...)

(If needed, I will copy the whole example here.)

My silly first question is does the "1/3M" in "$\min\{1/3M, 1\}$" means $\frac {M}{3}$ or $\frac{1}{3M}$ ?

And since I won't expect to figure out where the set {1/3M, 1} come from in the next hours, I will be very glad if you tell me.

Comment: Euh, the left limit is $-\infty$ whereas the right limit is $+\infty$. The limit doesn't exist unless you further specify the domain.

Comment: They mean $\frac1{3M}$. $\delta$ is supposed to get smaller the larger $M$ is, so that's the only thing that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it means $\frac{1}{3M}$.

You're trying to show that for every $M>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-1|<\delta$, then $\frac{1}{x^2-1}>M$. 
Notice that by the Triangle Inequality, $x<1+\delta$. 
Substituting and expanding we get
$$|\frac{1}{x^2-1}|=\frac{1}{|x-1||x+1|}>\frac{1}{\delta|x+1|}>\frac{1}{\delta|(1+\delta)+1|}=\frac{1}{\delta(2+\delta)}>\frac{1}{3\delta}=\frac{1}{3\,(1/(3M))}=M.$$
Therefore $\lim_{x\to1}|\frac{1}{x^2-1}|=+\infty$.
As @Arthur pointed out this only works for the absolute value of the function, so this is only a partial answer (though it does prove it is unbounded above).

Comment: This is a good answer, but it still doesn't address the main problem with the question formulation, namely that $x^2-1$ could be negative. For instance, you've just assumed $x^2-1=|x+1||x-1|$ when that's not true for $x<1$. Note, if we approach $1$ _from above_, your solution is exemplary.